# Internet connection working properly for some computers, but not others

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. If it isn't, please let me know where it would be appropriate, as this problem has been plaguing me for some time. At any rate, my problem is this:

I have two laptops, both running Windows 7 Home Premium, one of which I bring between home and my workplace. The first computer stays at home and is functionally a desktop. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with it -- it connects nicely to both the Internet and my router (Linksys WRT160N v3) and the connection speed is what I would expect.

The other laptop is problematic. While it connects perfectly at work, when I connect at home its connection is unusably slow. I can't find any substantial differences between how the two are configured. I've tried everything from virus scans, to adding the problematic computer to my router's DMZ, disabling and resetting firewalls on both the router and the computer, to resetting the network stack on the computer.

The problem laptop gets an IP address from the router just fine, and can occasionally load webpages.

Any insight anyone has would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you check `Control Panel / Internet Options (search for this) / Connections / LAN Settings` and see if any of the boxes are ticked?

Comment: Can you be at bit more precise what "unusably slow" means? Does it take long from the time you enter a URL to the time the site is loaded or if you try to download a file is the speed very low? If the download speed is low it might be that there is a proxy configured if it only takes long to load websites it might be a DNS problem...

Comment: Only "Automatically detect settings" is checked and by "unusably slow" I mean that the download/upload speeds are very low. It can take a full minute to load Google's homepage on that computer. My other computer loads it near-instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **Internet Connection Issues**, I hope this link will help you to troubleshoot. http://www.russharvey.bc.ca/resources/internet.html